# C#: Set integer for any given string

Tags: c#

I want to list the cost for every of my Upgrades.

Example:

String:"Faster Shooting",int: 10

I want an easy way to set a specific int for any string from a long list and later get the int, by the string

Comment: Are you after a [`Dictionary<string, int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0), which is a collection of key-value pairs. In this case, your key would be a `string` and your value an `int`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict["Faster Shooting"] = 10; // add "Faster Shooting" key, set to value 10.
dict["Faster Shooting"] = 15; // update "Faster Shooting" key, set to value 15.
Console.WriteLine(dict["Faster Shooting"]); // print "Faster Shooting" value
```

It also exposes `Add()`, `TryAdd()`, and other convenient methods, see @Heinzi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67386749/4302070) for an alternative using `Add()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want an easy way to set a specific X for any Y from a long list and later get the X, by the Y.

There's a built-in .NET data structure for *exactly* this purpose: A **dictionary** (sometimes called *map*, *hash map* or [*associative array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) in other programming languages).

Code example:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("Foo", 3);
dic.Add("Bar", 4);

Console.WriteLine(dic["Foo"]); // prints 3
```

Further examples can be found in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0).